# Convert dates of varying formats at once using dplyr

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

Let's say there is a list like this:

```
date
17-Dec-19
7/26/2018
02/01/2019
02-Mar-18
```

I suppose I could do several `ifelse` statements but is there a way I could just get them all formatted at once to look like:

```
date
2020-12-19
2018-07-26
2019-02-01
2018-03-02
```

Comment: The first date, year would be 2017 or 2019

Comment: The first date is ambiguous as it can be either be 2017-12-19 or 2019-12-17.  Similarly for last one.  It is better to have 4 digit year

Comment: @akrun first one is 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to convert to date with `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
df1$date <- anydate(df1$date)
df1$date
#[1] "2019-12-17" "2018-07-26" "2019-02-01" "2018-03-02"
```

---

Or with `parse_date_time`

```
library(lubridate)
as_date(parse_date_time(df1$date, c("dmy", "mdy")))
```

Comment: so the `anytime` route wont work on 17-Dec-19 format but parse_date_time does!

Comment: @JohnnyThomas By default, there is a set of formats available with `getFormats()` you can add new with `addFormats("%d-%b-%y")`